# mysql fetch records which have been added in the last 10 seconds?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch records that have been added in the last 10 seconds. I have a "zaman" column which has the timestamp of the record that tells when it has been added.

I have tried this one, however, it doesnt work (no errors)

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifs where writer='".$member[nick]."' AND 
zaman >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 SECOND) ORDER BY id DESC limit 5")     
or die(mysql_error());
```

What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and have been [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: @lonesomeday You should change your stock comment. They've been removed in PHP 7, it's not the future any more.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. Copied from meta, now changed here

Comment: The query looks like it should work. Are you sure there were new records added in the past 10 seconds?

Comment: $member[nick] should be $member['nick'] Enable php warnings and errors.

Comment: What's the difference Kostas, both works.

Comment: @user3304007 You should be getting a warning saying that there's no constant named `nick` and it's treating it as a string.

Comment: What do you get from the query `SELECT NOW(), MAX(zaman) FROM notifs WHERE writer = '$member[nick]'`?

Comment: @user3304007 the difference is that when it encounters `$member[nick]`, PHP expects to find a constant named `nick`. If it cannot find it then it assumes the programmer wanted to write `'nick'` and issues a notice you probably ignore. I'll let you figure out if your code still works when you define the `nick` constant and its value is not `'nick'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new record is saved, record it's time saved. Then, when running the fetch query, get all values that are greater than or equal to current time - 10.
assuming zaman is a epoche timestamp...

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifs where writer='".$member[nick]."' AND 
zaman >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-10 ORDER BY id DESC limit 5")
```

Comment: How is that different from what he's currently doing?

Comment: So UNIX_TIMESTAMP() gives current time ?

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns a numeric timestamp, not a datetime.

Comment: @Barmar, he has said his times are saved as timestamp, so that is what is necessary.

Comment: Yes timestamp is needed. Thanks.

Comment: MySQL TIMESTAMP datatype is not a number.

Comment: Why are you telling us that - slightly irrelevant...?

Comment: @CasparWylie Your solution would be correct if the datatype were `INT`, not `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Ah i see, well they are extremely interchangeable, and he has not specified if his field is INT or TIMESTAMP. Worth pointing out though. cheers.

Comment: No problem. Accept as answer if so. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifs where writer='".$member[nick]."' AND zaman >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 SECOND) ORDER BY id DESC limit 5")
```